# How can i execute a command on remote server to get the list of printers

Tags: windows-7

```
C:\Users\523656>net view blahh.bag.yyy.com| find /i "print"
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

I was expecting that it should ask me user name and password or may be something like

```
C:\Users\523656>net view -u username -p password blahh.bag.yyy.com| find /i "print"
```

I am trying to get the list of printer nameson multiple servers or search a printeron multiple servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `wmic` for that:
`wmic /node:blahh.bag.com  printer get name`
You can set user and password with
`/USER
/PASSWORD`
(if you set only user it should ask you for password).

`/Node` can specify a list of servers, run `wmic /node /?` to see options